# Взаимодействие с элементами из другого класса на c#

Tags: c#

В программе есть дополнительный класс, в котором методы должны изменять значения в программе (например менять значение label....) но из другого класса я "не вижу" элементы...
Как мне их увидеть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или, чтобы не нарушать концепцию инкапсуляции, сделать для необходимых Вам полей открытые свойства или методы по изменению их значений.

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    private Label myLabel;

    public SetMyLabelText(string text)
    {
        myLabel.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Объявить их с модификатором public?